# CUDA installation for TensorFlow. No cuDNN v4 for CUDA 7.5 at NVIDIA

Tags: cuda, tensorflow, cudnn

I'm trying to install CUDA (to use it for TensorFlow). It's recommended to use cuDNN v.4 and CUDA 7.5. But at https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download

There are only cuDNN v.4 for CUDA 7.0 and cuDNN v.5 (release candidate) for CUDA 7.5. Where I can get cuDNN v.4 for CUDA 7.5? Thank you.

Comment: You just download cudnn v4 for 7.0 and it will work with 7.5

Comment: 7.5 is available at https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Answer (score 3):

As @fabrizioM pointed out, you can use cuDNN v.4 for CUDA 7.0. I also spent a lot of time to install CUDA/cuDNN.

For the reference, https://no2147483647.wordpress.com/2016/01/16/setup-amazon-aws-gpu-instance-with-mxnet/ has great instructions:

```
tar -zxf cudnn-7.0-linux-x64-v4.0-rc.tgz 
cd cuda
sudo cp lib64/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
sudo cp include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include/
```

Answer (score 2):

No problem In that. I've installed cuda 7.5 and using cuDNN v4 on ubuntu 16.04. There is no problem in that.

Answer (score 0):

Installing CuDNN from scratch is painful.

As of October 2016, AWS is offering pre-built AMI's with NVIDIA CUDA 7.5 Pre-installed. Yipieee!

Plese see -

[AWS Blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-p2-instance-type-for-amazon-ec2-up-to-16-gpus/)

[AWS AMI GPU Image](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01LZMLK1K?qid=1475196062961&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title)

[NVIDIA Digits4](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01LZN28VD?qid=1475196062961&sr=0-3&ref_=srh_res_product_title)

Comment: Not sure about why the downvote. I really think AWS AMI is removing lot of painful steps to setup CUDA and this answer would help future users.